# Why does jquery throw this error in uncompressed version only?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a bear of a time trying to understand why I get an error from jquery but only if I am using the uncompressed version.
If I load the uncompressed jquery-1.11.2.js I get an error, however, if I load the minified version of the same jquery version no error?  I know this is probably not much information but I don't know what else to put here.

The code that throws the error is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#cell").mask("(999) 999-9999");
  $("#altphone").mask("(999) 999-9999");

});
```

the errors are:

> TypeError: a.browser is undefined
>
> TypeError: $(...).mask is not a function

In the head section of my page I load

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How sure are you that they are the same version? You said you're loading 1.11.2 but `.browser` was [removed in JQuery 1.9](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/).

Comment: this is from the uncompressed file  /*!
 * jQuery JavaScript Library v1.11.2
 * http://jquery.com/  and this from the minified version   /*! jQuery v1.11.2 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license */  both come straight from the jquery download site

Comment: Correct. But evidently it seems like somewhere you're using `.browser`, and if the minified version *isn't* throwing an error, then it must be a version earlier than 1.9.

Comment: the minified version is 1.11.2 as shown above jst downloaded it a few mins ago and the same results

Comment: Well, then perhaps look at your MaskedInput. The [changelog](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) on their website specifically lists *JQuery 1.9 Compatibility* in Version 1.3.1, but you're importing version 1.3. Try upgrading MaskedInput.

Comment: ahhhhhhh I shall try that

Comment: I don't see any error: see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7fcfcfxp/)

Comment: I just upgraded to maskedinput 1.4 and that solved the problem.  Another question please?  Would this also cause my select boxes to not function intermittently?

Comment: It could be that all your jquery versions are just fine and youre trying to access stuff before theyre loaded. Make sure your scripts that require jquery are below the actual call to jqyery.

Comment: as I said upgraded to the latest version of masked input solved this delema

Comment: Why don't you just use jQuery 3.x (or at least 2.2.x)?